# Safe Memory allocation during a c++ parallel algorithms invocation (with Intel TBB)?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, parallel-processing, tbb

I would like to understand whether a memory allocation inside a function which a thread executes is safe for the c++ parallel algorithms. Consider the following situation:

```
std::for_each(std::execution::par, first, last, func),
```

with `func` being the function object. During a call to `func` (CPU and GPU) memory is allocated. When too many threads execute and allocate memory, the system would run out of memory and throw an exception. So far, this has not happened. I wonder if I was merely lucky or whether the execution policy considers such memory constraints or catches memory-related exceptions? The parallel algorithm is implemented through Intel TBB.

Comment: If you allocates some memory space freed at the end of the function, there is nothing wrong with that apart from the fact that it is probably inefficient and you could use a lot of memory (as you pointed out in the post). Allocation on a GPU is probably a problem because the memory is much more scarce on such a device (with hardware limitations on malloc). If the memory is not freed directly, then this is probably a bad idea to use for_each. Consider using *tasks* instead. Alternatively, it may be a good idea to used a per-worker scratch storage location regarding your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tasks instead of threads as Intel oneTBB works on tasks instead of low-level threads that is, it creates tasks instead of thread and it will map these tasks onto hardware at runtime.
The Task scheduler takes care of mapping the tasks onto threads.
You should explicitly free the memory space when we use for_each in the source code as suggested by Jerome Richard.